# I am looking for steps to update a game to SDL 2.0

Tags: c++, c, sdl

I am working on a project with my friend where we have to update existing version of a game which uses SDL 1.2 to use SDL 2.0 header files and functions.
I would like to know what is the standard procedure we follow while updating already existing source code to newer libraries.
The code has 28 source files with 11 header files and makes extensive use of keyboard and mouse events and sounds as well.
All the source files use c++ and sdl.Most source files are around 200 lines of code.
i have a time period of about 3 months to make the changes.I would like to know how to write a basic summary of my schedule for that time period on a week-by week basis or 2 weeks basis.
Can anyone provide me proper steps for the same so I can make a schedule for the same?

Comment: Wait, the game is only ~6 KLOC? I'm not sure you'll be able to realistically pad the schedule out to three months... ;)

Comment: Sounds like a good summer project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of standard procedures, but here are my thoughts:

In general, I can think of two approaches to porting an existing software to either another language, use of another library, or any change of the such; with minimal structural change
 or with major structural change.

**Minimal structural change** means that you leave the structure of your program intact, and start replacing every single bit of it by its equivalent in the other library. For example, if porting from glut to SDL, you replacing the glut window creation with SDL's, keyboard handling with SDL's etc, all independently.

This method is faster, in the sense that all the changes are small and local. You are also less likely to introduce bugs. The result may not be so efficient though, as the structure of the program is not originally designed for this new library.

**Major structural change** means that based on the new library, you rewrite a large part of the program that is dependent on that library. For example, if switching from C++'s STL to C's standard libraries, rewriting `string` with its equivalent in C that keeps allocating/freeing/copying doesn't make sense because your approach should be fundamentally different.

This approach requires a lot more work but in the end will give you a much better quality.

---

Back to your particular case, I'm not sure how different SDL 2 is from SDL 1.2, but my guess is it's not fundamentally different. Therefore, I believe the first method should work in your case. That is, you should work out the equivalents in SDL 2 of the stuff you did in SDL 1.2, and replace them in your code accordingly.